# Why won't placeholder work in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I try to run a simple statement using tf.placeholder() I get the result below.

```
X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,height,width,channels))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-6f535655ed45>", line 1, in <module>
    X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,height,width,channels))

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

After doing some reading it seems this can be related to having version 2 of tensorflow rather than an earlier version. But I checked and it appears I have 1.14.

```
pip list
Package                            Version            
---------------------------------- -------------------
tensorboard                        1.14.0             
tensorboard-plugin-wit             1.6.0.post3        
tensorflow                         1.14.0             
tensorflow-estimator               1.14.0
```

I am very new to this and was trying to follow a tutorial from a book, any help is appreciated. For context I'm attempting to run this in Spyder as a part of the Anaconda distribution for Python 3.7.

Edit: I forgot to include my attempts at using some version of tf.compat.placeholder() as well.

```
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,height,width,channels))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-d9a798a5972c>", line 1, in <module>
    X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,height,width,channels))

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat'
```

Edit 2: After more testing, the code will run in Jupyter but not in Spyder, so I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Do you have a file called tensorflow.py ?

Comment: No, the file I'm using in my directory is called "tensorflow testing.py" and there are no other files with that name.

Comment: Open a python shell or an IDE, import tensorflow, and then call print(tensorflow), and report the output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling tensorflow

Using pip:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator
pip install tensorflow
```

Using conda:

```
conda remove tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Comment: I did the PIP steps and attempted again, am now receiving this error: "RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution" when executing tf.compat.v1.placeholder()

Comment: Try adding tf.disable_v2_behavior() after you import TensorFlow. It disables version 2 behaviour.

Comment: One of those options worked, thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder` as suggested in the documentation ( [see here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder) )

Comment: I forgot to include my results from attempting that as well, will update question.